# What does a Mitre Saw offer that a Table Saw does not?

Tags: framing, woodworking, powertools, mdf

I have a range of MDF Panels and strips of Solid Wood that I would like to turn into Picture Frames.  As such, each piece of MDF/Wood will need to have a 45-degree angle cut into each end.

In order to achieve such cuts, I have been looking at the purchase of various Mitre and Table Saws.  I can see that with the assistance of a Mitre Gauge, the Table Saw is able to complete such a task.

With this in mind, I was wondering what a Mitre Saw provided that a Table Saw did not.

I am new to Woodwork but it seems that a Mitre Saw is limited to 1 task whereas the Table Saw is able to perform a variety of tasks.  Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Welcome and hello See you going with the mdf from last post..    Keeping  it short..You will need  both.. Table saw to rip your  sheets of mdf  and can do your rabbit and dado   ..Will do miters little tuff  for your wants    Miter  box that does compound  for crosscuts and angle witch is great for what you do   All finish carpenters have these 2 tools can do almost any thing ..    miter box  first choice.  table saw Do not know if you have nail gun , that great tool to..

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I was considering a Nail Gun but would prefer to avoid the visibility of Nails, albeit low visibility.  As such, I am contemplating suitable Wood Glue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can make any mitre cut with a table saw provided you have the correct jigs and guides.  But, it's a LOT simpler and quicker to use a mitre saw to make mitre cuts.  For "casual" work or just one-offs, then go ahead and use your table saw.  If you're wanting to have quick and repeatable angle cuts, then get a mitre saw.

If you have to choose only one due to space or cost limitations, you might consider a radial-arm saw instead of a table saw.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the Radial Arm Saw.  That is a new one for me.  After a quick browse, I can see that it was the predecessor to the Mitre Saw.  Am I right in assuming that the Radial Arm Saw is also capable of cutting long lengths of Wood?  As I will be looking for create Picture Frames, I will need to cut various Rabbet Depths and Widths.  Is this something that the Radial Arm Saw would lack in capability?

Comment: A radial arm saw can do rabbets  I is a great saw  Not used as much as they used to ..Miter table saw would be great for you ..Enjoy

Comment: @Craig Yes, you can "rip" on a radial arm saw.  The limitation, however, when compared to the table saw is that the maximum width of the cut is restricted by the "throat" of the saw.  That's the distance between the arm support post and the maximum extension of the saw power head.

Comment: @jwh20 ... Thanks for the insight.  Something else for me to factor in, when finally deciding on suitable Tools. :-)

Comment: After you get going please ,comment on your findings